# Stored Procedure returns a temporary table that I need to convert to a CSV file

Tags: sql-server, csv, datagridview, datatable

I basically have a stored procedure that I call through a method:

```
Time_Tracker.BLL.ResultsManager.GetCSV(Convert.ToDateTime("2014-01-11"));
```

It returns 8 columns of data ranging from 25 to 150 records.

I need to be able to convert it to a CSV file to a path of the users choosing. I am able to get it into my code behind as an array ( `Results[] TEST = new Results[25];` ) and have verified that the data is O.K. I see plenty of posts were they use a `DataTable` as a source to convert to CSV, but I am not sure how to load a `DataTable` from the method that calls the stored procedure. Same thing with `DataGridView`, not sure how to load the data into a `DataGridView` either.

I have also seen methods were they use `SqlDataAdapter` to populate a `DataTable`. Since I use methods to that work directly with stored procedures, I don't want to have to use `SqlDataAdapter` and provide the database configuration info each time.

IF someone could help me load it into a `DataTable` or `DataGridView`, I think I can figure it out from there.

Thank you in advance.

Eric

Comment: Do you need to process the data in your program to any extent more than passing it from the database to a csv file? Could there be NULL values in the data? Could there be commas in the data?

Answer (score 0):

Just define a data table and use the load command to move the data from the reader to the data table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx

This is right from MSDN.  I added two lines to load a data table.

```
-- Code from msdn
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

-- This is my addition
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

I still do not understand what you are trying to do.  You can create a data table, xml record set, via coding.

The code below can be used to translate an array to a DataTable.  Some work is needed on your side to add your details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skef0k7a(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// Create sample Customers table.
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.TableName = "Customers";

// Create two columns, ID and Name.
DataColumn idColumn = table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

// Set the ID column as the primary key column.
table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { idColumn };

table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, "Mary" });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Andy" });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Peter" });
table.AcceptChanges();
return table;
```

I hope this helps.  If not, I still do not get the business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (See Below). I will mark this as solved and once again, Thank You for your help !

```
       foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
              if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                {
                    if (dr[i] is DateTime)
                    {
                        if (((DateTime)dr[i]).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) // Time Since Midnight (in Seconds)
                        {
                            sw.Write(((DateTime)dr[i]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                    }
                }

                if (i < iColCount - 1) sw.Write(",");
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
```

Comment: I don't see a link to mark the post as answered. Can someone close out this thread? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing for anyone else looking for help:

```
  protected void btnCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // HATE EXPOSING THE DATABASE CONNECTION THIS WAY !!!
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(DAL.DBUtils.SqlConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[usp.CSV_OUT]";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateBeg", Time_Tracker.Utilities.TimeCard_Start_Date());
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            sqlConnection1.Close();
            ExportToCSV(dt, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVPath"].ToString(), "CSV_Hours_Data_" + Time_Tracker.Utilities.TimeCard_Start_Date().AddDays(+6).ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".csv");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.ErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.StackTrace, @"Time_Tracker.txt");
        }
    }


    public static void ExportToCSV(DataTable dt, string strFilePath, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath + fileName, false);
            // Write the headers.
            int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
                if (i < iColCount - 1) sw.Write(",");
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            // Write rows.
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                    {
                        string output = dr[i].ToString();

                        if (dr[i] is DateTime)
                        {
                            if (((DateTime)dr[i]).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) // Time Since Midnight (in Seconds)
                            {
                                output = (((DateTime)dr[i]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                            }
                        }
                        if (output.Contains(";") || output.Contains("\""))
                            output = '"' + output.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(output, @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)"))
                            output = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(output, @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)"));
                        sw.Write(output);
                    }

                    if (i < iColCount - 1) sw.Write(",");
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            sw.Close();
            // Causes Save As Dialog box to appear for user.
            String FileName = fileName;
            String FilePath = strFilePath;
            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
            response.TransmitFile(FilePath + FileName);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.ErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.StackTrace, @"Time_Tracker.txt");
        }
    }
```